# How to decode contract storage returned data

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, scale-codec

How do i decode this Hex string to String. It is storage data returned from a contract, using Polkadot-JS.

```
{
  Ok: {
    flags: [],
    data: '0x000901ac6ed6fbae6c444e5d2aac0720ddf3436728c8579cc78235e93f348805d590ac23ed7dd9728d610abf0a5e55fd661eaa783234ee554d8964c2d912968b107df28523'
  }
}
```